# Hudson\Jenkins individual build step results

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins

I am trying to get the individual build step results of any Hudson\Jenkins Job. Is it possible to get the data via Hudson Java API inside the plugin or through remote api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following link will get you some XML describing the last successful build. This is going through the Jenkins API

```
http://<Your_Servers_Hostname>:8080/jenkins/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml
```

Please notice that you get a  tag that contains the state of the job.

If you don't like xml, you can get json like this:

```
http://<Your_Servers_Hostname>:8080/jenkins/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json
```

and a Python api like:

```
http://<Your_Servers_Hostname>:8080/jenkins/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/python
```

If you want more documentation, go to

```
http://<Your_Servers_Hostname>:8080/jenkins/api/
```

and it should give you some good information about the Jenkins API. You can even construct your URL to be a query, for example:

```
http://<Your_Servers_Hostname>:8080/jenkins/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?xpath=/*/result
```

That will give you an xml fragment with just the result of the latest successful build.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Hudson instead of Jenkins.The remote api url you have mentioned does return the results of the build overall but not the results of the individual build step. I need the results of each build steps of the single build individually.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a reason for using Hudson instead of Jenkins? The developer community has moved almost exclusively to Jenkins, and the feature that you are looking for could have been implemented there.